# SOQL: order by count of subquery records

Tags: soql

In SOQL, is it possible to order the results by the count of records in a subquery? Eg:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    (
        SELECT
            OpportunityId,
            Role
        FROM OpportunityContactRoles
    )
FROM Contacts
ORDER BY <count of OpportunityContactRoles>
```

If so, what is the syntax of the `ORDER BY` clause? If this cannot be done directly, is there a way to cheat around it?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know not directly in the query, but you can in Apex by wrapping the `Contact` in a class that implements [comparable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm). The code would look something like this:

```
private class Wrapper implements Comparable {
    Contact c;
    Wrapper(Contact c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
    public Integer compareTo(Object o) {
        Wrapper that = (Wrapper) o;
        Integer thatChildren = that.c.OpportunityContactRoles.size();
        Integer thatChildren = this.c.OpportunityContactRoles.size();
        if (thisChildren < thatChildren) return -1;
        else if (thisChildren > thatChildren) return 1;
        else return 0;
    }
}

private Contact[] queryAndSort() {
    Wrapper[] wrappers = new Wrapper[] {};
    for (Contact c : [
            SELECT Id, (SELECT OpportunityId, Role FROM OpportunityContactRoles)
            FROM Contact
            WHERE ...
            ]) {
        wrapper.add(new Wrapper(c));
    }
    wrappers.sort();
    Contact[] contacts = new Contact[] {};
    for (Wrapper w : wrappers) {
        contacts.add(w.c);
    }
    return contacts;
}
```

(You could instead use an [aggregate query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_agg_fns.htm) to count and in that case can also order by the count if you don't need the `OpportunityContactRole` data values.)

Comment: This is basically the same solution I had come up with, but it breaks down when fetching large data sets in pages via a remote action. I ended up having to sort the complete data set on the front-end.

Comment: @asgallant Another approach would be to keep a count of the OpportunityContactRole objects on the Contact via triggers and order by that.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the moment has passed for the original poster, but assuming from the original post that the question to answer is 'which Contacts have the most Opportunity Roles', this can be achieved in SOQL by approaching it from the other direction:

```
SELECT ContactId, Count(Id)
FROM OpportunityContactRole
GROUP BY ContactId
ORDER By Count(Id) DESC
```

[image]

You don't get the individual OpportunityIds and Roles this way though.  GROUP BY ROLLUP and GROUPING(fieldName) may be useful, but I haven't figured out how to then order by Contacts with the most number of Roles, so you would be back to Apex to achieve that.  Also watch out for the limitation that you can't use queryMore() with a GROUP BY.
These subjects are covered in the GROUP BY section of the docs:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby.htm

Answer (score 0):

Using apex for counting number of sub-records of SOQL is given below:

```
map<id,integer> contactIDVscontactRoles = new map<id,integer>();
integer i;
for(Contact conObj : listOfContacts)
{
   i=0;
   for(OpportunityContactRoles ocrObj : conObj.OpportunityContactRoles)
   {
      i++;
   }
   contactIDVscontactRoles.put(conObj.id , i);
 //map is used for storing number of contact roles against corresponding contact.
}
```